# From SETH to circuit lowerbounds

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, lower-bounds, circuits

Are there reductions from SETH (Strong Exponential Time Hypothesis) to lowerbounds against threshold circuits? (maybe for computing Boolean functions of the form OR-of-AND-of-OR)

---

In threshold circuits I am allowing for circuits which end with a summing gate and hence these circuits are computing real valued functions on the Boolean cube.